# Worldpay - How to register to business manager / merchant admin?

Tags: magento, worldpay

I'm wanting to start taking payments using Worldpay through Magento, so according to this page I need to use the 'Business Manager'

https://www.worldpay.com/uk/support/sme-support/get-started-with-online-payments

All I see is "Login to get started", but where do I go to actually register for this? I registered at https://online.worldpay.com/signup but that doesn't seem to be the same for logging in at https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin as the guide suggests.

Comment: I think you should ask the question at that domain instead. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?